# Fullcalendar on Double Click show popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, fullcalendar

Want to open a Popup when double click on any date. So that I can Insert an Event on specific date. How can I implement that?

I am sharing my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // ----- This Parameter is Used for displaying Next,Previous,Today,Month,Week & Day ------ //   
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',
            ignoreTimezone: false
        },
        selectable  : true,
        selectHelper: true,         
        editable    : true,
        events      : "ajax/schedule_response.php",//Fetching JSON From PHP File//

        // ----- This Parameter is Used for Dragging Events ------ //   
        eventDrop   : function(event, delta) {

            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : "ajax/schedule_update.php",
                    data: "id="+event.id, 
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend:  function() 
                        {
                        },
                    success: function(html)
                        {
                        }
                 });
            },

        // ----- This Parameter is Used for Resizing Events ------ //   
        eventResize : function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : "ajax/schedule_update.php",
                data: "id="+event.id,
                cache: false, 
                beforeSend:  function() 
                    {
                    },
                success: function(html)
                    {
                    }
            });
            },

        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try  this option**

```
 eventRender: function(event, element) {
          element.bind('dblclick', function() {
             alert('double click!');
          });
       }
```

Comment: How can i get the clicked date in Y-m-d form ?

Comment: create a variable before fullcalendar plugin call.then assing that variable in    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

       var x=date;
  

    }

Comment: date is providing : Tue Dec 03 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time) . I simply need 2013-12-03

Comment: date=date.getFullYear()+'-'+date.getMonth()+'-'+date.getDate();